# How can I display my machine's IP address on a TTY login screen?

Tags: login, internet, tty, ifconfig

The server I administrate has a dynamic IP address assigned by DHCP, which is inconvenient. When I want to SSH into it, I have to first log in by hand and use `ifconfig` to find its current IP address. Thankfully, it lives about two feet from where I sit.

I know how to edit /etc/issue to show different values before the login prompt is delivered to the display, but I'd like to know if it's possible for /etc/issue to display the current IP address of eth0 (re-evaluated at boot time) so that I can see it and then ssh in without having to log in to run ifconfig.

Comment: Can conky be used in the login screen? If so you could make all sorts of info handy.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of Debian 8/jessie you can use the `\4` and `\6` escape characters to output the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. So the `/etc/issue` file:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

eth0: \4{eth0}
```

Would output something like the following at the login console:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 myserver tty1

eth0: 192.168.1.100
myserver login:
```

I imagine Ubuntu would provide similar functionality (at least in newer releases)

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the answer marked as correct didn't, probably an issue with the grep comment, in any case, thanks for posting this.

Comment: It still works on Debian 9 :)

Comment: This can be abbreviated further: `eth0: \4` will give the IP address of the first non-loopback interface.

Comment: Tested on Debian 10 and still works, but changed a little: `\4{enp2s5}`

Answer (score 13):

`/etc/issue` is unfortunately a plain text, it has some options you can add to it (see `man agetty`) but not the IP address of eth0.

If you put this in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "eth0 IP: $IP" > /etc/issue
```

Then you will see something like this:

```
eth0: 192.168.0.2
myServer login:
```

Comment: Please note for anyone running this, this will overwrite the contents of /etc/issue. You could add steps to grep out the previous "eth*" lines and then append them.

Comment: This solution worked on Alpine

Answer (score 2):

Building on Alex's answer and Rebs' comment, this is what I have for my `/etc/rc.local` file (only relevant lines):

```
PRE_MSG="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS" # this is from the original /etc/issue

IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')

IP_MSG="Server IP Address:"

printf "%s %s %s\n\n%s %s\n\n" "$PRE_MSG" '\n' '\l' "$IP_MSG" "$IP" > "/etc/issue"
```

The `printf` command does the magic. Unfortunately putting the `'\n'` and `'\l'` inside the format string ended up replacing the first one with the new line character and the `/etc/issue` file was messed up.

So long story short, these 4 lines keep the original info displayed by `/etc/issue` file and add the `Server IP Address:` message.

And as Rebs' said, keep in mind that every time you reboot the server, this script will override the `/etc/issue` file, so maybe try it inside a different script and on a different file and once it's working, transfer the changes over...

Good luck and happy BASHing :)

Answer (score 1):

With systemd you can do `systemctl edit getty@` with something like:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c '[ ! -f /etc/.issue.orig ] && cp /etc/issue /etc/.issue.orig; int=`ls /sys/class/net|grep enp|head -1`; sed -r "s/\\\\\\n/[\\\\\\4\{$$int\}]/" < /etc/.issue.orig > /etc/issue'
```

Then `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart getty@tty1`

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 19.04, I followed these steps:

I created the file: `/etc/network/if-up.d/update-issue` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
PREFIX="Ubuntu 19.04 - dev"
IPADDRS=$(hostname -I | tr " " "\n" | grep -v "^$" | sort -t . -k 1,1n | head -1 | tr "\n" " ")
echo "$PREFIX\n\nIP: $IPADDRS\n" > /etc/issue
```

I then marked the file as executable: `chmod 0755 /etc/network/if-up.d/update-issue`

Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Nurchi, Alex and Steve's answers & the comment from Reb,

The following will grep the old IP out and add in any non local (127.) IP addresses. 
My server is a VM and doesn't have eth0.
Testing on Ubuntu 18.04

Place in `/etc/network/if-up.d/update-issue`

```
#!/bin/sh
MSG=$(cat /etc/issue | grep -v IP)
IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet' | grep -v '127' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2 }')
printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$MSG" "IP: $IP" > /etc/issue
```

Then `chmod 0755 /etc/network/if-up.d/update-issue`

The only difference between my answer and Steve's is the addition of the grep lines to remove the IP line, capture the message and readd it along with the new/updated IP

Answer (score 0):

This works for ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well.
Just make sure you're using the right interface. The output of `ifconfig` will show all interfaces, update the same interface in `/etc/issue`

[image]